# How do I change HTML Label Text Once File Has Been Selected using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Thanks for viewing my question. I have a form below that has a file input field. Safe to say I have hidden this input field, and am now using the label as the primary "button" to select the files. Once a user clicks on the "Upload Picture..." label, I want the text inside the label to change from "Upload Picture..." to the file name. I'm following this tutorial below however the javascript written (in the tutorial) is for multiple files being able to be selected by the user. I only am allowing my users to select ONE file. This is a change your profile picture page to give a little insight as to what this form does.

Here is the code:

```
<!-- Change Picture Form -->
            <div class="changepic-wrap">
              <form action="changepicauth.php" method="post">
                <input type="file" name="profilepic" id="profilepic" class="inputfile">
                <br>
                <label for="profilepic">
                  <img src="/images/profile/upload.png" />
                  Upload Picture...
                </label>
                <br>
                <div class="button-wrap">
                  <button>Change Picture</button>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
```

Here is the tutorial:

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2015/09/15/styling-customizing-file-inputs-smart-way/

Can someone help explain to me what i have to do? I'm thinking something along the lines of an eventlistener but i'm not sure about javascript. I'm a backend dev and know very little about javascript. I do NOT WISH TO USE JQUERY. Straight javascript only.

Thanks again for your help StackOverflow members! :D

Edit:
Some people have said that the text is changing already. It's not... I want the LABEL text to change. The "File Input" tag has two parts to it. The button, and the text next to the button. I've hidden the input tag using the following SASS code. This way only the "Upload Picture..." label text is displayed. Please make sure to add this SASS code to your file so you can see that the LABEL text does not change.

```
.inputfile
        width: 0.1px
        height: 0.1px
        opacity: 0
        overflow: hidden
        position: absolute
        z-index: -1
```

Comment: Working for me. Maybe You have duplicate id profilepic?

Comment: Check above for an edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the javascript `onchange` event to detect when the value of the `#profilepic` `input` changes.

When it does, you can capture the new `value` of the `#profilepic` `input` and replace the text of the label with that `value`.

**Example:**

```js
var profilePic = document.getElementById('profilepic'); /* finds the input */

function changeLabelText() {
    var profilePicValue = profilePic.value; /* gets the filepath and filename from the input */
    var fileNameStart = profilePicValue.lastIndexOf('\\'); /* finds the end of the filepath */
    profilePicValue = profilePicValue.substr(fileNameStart + 1); /* isolates the filename */
    var profilePicLabelText = document.querySelector('label[for="profilepic"]').childNodes[2]; /* finds the label text */
    if (profilePicValue !== '') {
        profilePicLabelText.textContent = profilePicValue; /* changes the label text */
    }
}

profilePic.addEventListener('change',changeLabelText,false); /* runs the function whenever the filename in the input is changed */
```

```html
<div class="changepic-wrap">
<form action="changepicauth.php" method="post">
<input type="file" name="profilepic" id="profilepic" class="inputfile">
<br>
<label for="profilepic">
<img src="/images/profile/upload.png" />
Upload Picture...
</label>
<br>
<div class="button-wrap">
<button>Change Picture</button>
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you comment out the javascript so i can see what's happening? I don't know javascript all that well, but i could learn more if i knew what that javascript code does. :D Thanks for your reply. I'll be testing this soon.

Sent from Mobile

Comment: Can you display JUST the name and not the file path?

Comment: I've added comments after most of the javascript lines so that you can see what each of those lines does.

Comment: In Firefox 48, only the filename comes up. In which browser are you seeing the filepath as well? Let me know so I can reproduce the behaviour and then I'll put together a regex to fix it which I can test in that browser.

Comment: I'm using Google Chrome latest build public released build. Thanks for commenting out those things. That really helps. I definitely love how i can LEARN from stackoverflow and not just get answers. Thanks alot man!

Comment: I've added two extra lines showing you how to isolate the `filename` from the rest of the `filepath`, using `lastIndexOf` and `substr`. The snippet should work as intended in all browsers now.

Comment: Hey @Rounin unfortunately this isn't working in my site... :/

I'm putting the javascript inside of <script>... and then i didn't change my html at all seeing how there were no changes done by you for the HTML. 

Not really seeing where this is going wrong. The text just isn't updating. It's really really weird seeing how the code snippet works, and yet on my site it's not working. I'll be trying to recreate this in a separate file and see if it's just the file itself or something. Hmmm... any ideas?

Comment: Edit: I'm an idiot and used <style> and not <script> wow... monday's man..

Comment: unfortunately the code is still not working, can you please look at this new question and give your reply if you have the time?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38837056/how-to-change-label-text-upon-file-being-selected-within-form-using-javascript

Answer (score 1):

You can use `change` event, select element having `for` attribute value equal to `event.target`: `#profilepic` element `id`, set the `.innerHTML` of selected element to `event.target.files[0]` `.name`

```js
document.getElementById("profilepic")
.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
  document.querySelector("[for=" + e.target.id + "]")
  .innerHTML = e.target.files[0].name;
})
```

```css
.inputfile {
  width: 0.1px;
  height: 0.1px;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<!-- Change Picture Form -->
<div class="changepic-wrap">
  <form action="changepicauth.php" method="post">
    <input type="file" name="profilepic" id="profilepic" class="inputfile">
    <br>
    <label for="profilepic">
      <img src="/images/profile/upload.png" />Upload Picture...
    </label>
    <br>
    <div class="button-wrap">
      <button>Change Picture</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I'll be combining both of your answers together to get JUST the name WITH the image as well.